# Proof of Basis Representation Theorem; How do we know b_k(1) = 1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I am currently making my way through George E. Andrews' *Number Theory* and am having some trouble with his proof for the basis representation theorem.

I follow the proof up until he applies Corollary 1.1, which states that "If $m$ and $n$ are positive integers and if $m>1$, then $n<m^n$." To be clear, I understand the corollary and I am pretty sure I know how/why it applies in the proof. However it is followed by something that is never explained clearly.

To start, let me introduce the proof. I will more or less copy it directly from the text to reduce potential for miscommunication.

> **Theorem 1.3** *(Basis Representation Theorem): Let k be any integer larger than 1. Then, for each positive integer n, there exists a representation*

$$n=a_0k^s+a_1k^{s-1}+...+a_s, \ \ \ \ \ \ (1.2.1)$$

where $a_0 \neq0$, and where each $a_i$ is nonnegative and less than k. Furthermore, this representation of n is unique; it is called the representation of n to the base k.

Remark: For each base $k$, we can also represent $0$ by letting all the $a_i$ be equal to $0$.

Proof: Let $b_k(n)$ denote the number of representations of $n$ to the base $k$. We must show that $b_k(n)$ always equals $1$.

If some of the coefficients $a_i$ in a particular representation of $n$ are equal to zero, they may be excluded without affecting representation. Therefore,

$$n=a_0k^s+a_1k^{s-1}+...+a_{s-t}k^t,$$

where $a_0\neq0$ and $a_{s-t}\neq0$. Then,

$$n-1=a_0k^s+a_1
k^{s-1}+...+a_{s-t}k^t-1$$
$$=a_0k^s+a_1k^{s-1}+...+(a_{s-t}-1)k^t+k^t-1$$
$$=a_0k^s+a_1k^{s-1}+...+(a_{s-t}-1)k^t+\sum_{j=0}^{t-1}(k-1)k^j,$$

by virtue of Theorem 1.2, which states $\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}x^j$. Here $x=k$ and $n=t$. From this we see that for each representation of $n$ to the base $k$, we can find a representation of $n-1$. If $n$ has another representation to the base $k$, the same procedure will yield a new representation of $n-1$. Consequently,

$$b_k(n)≤b_k(n-1),\ \ \ \ \ \ (1.2.2)$$

This inequality implies the following inequalities:

$$b_k(n+2)≤b_k(n+1)≤b_k(n),$$
$$b_k(n+3)≤b_k(n+2)≤b_k(n+1)≤b_k(n),$$

and, in general, if $m≥n+4$,

$$b_k(m)≤b_k(m-1)≤b_k(m-2)≤...≤b_k(n+1)≤b_k(n).$$

My problem emerges here:

> Since $k^n>n$ by Corollary 1.1, and since $k^n$ clearly has at least one representation (namely, itself), we see that

$$1≤b_k(k^n)≤b_k(n)≤b_k(1)=1.$$

The extreme entries in this set of inequalities are ones, so that all of the interediate entries must be equal to 1. Thus $b_k(n)=1$, and Theorem 1.3 is established.

I am going to describe how I understand this.

Clearly, as $n$ increases, $b_k(n)$ must either decrease or remain the same, as shown by the inequality $b_k(m)≤b_k(m-1)≤b_k(m-2)≤...≤b_k(n+1)≤b_k(n).$ Since, $k^n > n$, we know that $b_k(k^n)≤b_k(n).$ And all of this must be greater than or equal to one, since we know $k^n$ has at least one representation. But where have we established that $b_k(n)≤b_k(1)$? Clearly $1$ also has at least one representation, but how have we shown that it does not have more? Similarly, $b_k(n)≤b_k(1)$ implies that $n ≥ 1$; where did we establish this?

Answer (score 1):

That $b_k(n)\le b_k(1)$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ follows from $(1.2.2)$ by a straightforward induction argument: if $b_k(n)\le b_k(n-\ell)$ for some $\ell\ge 0$, and $n-\ell>1$, then

$$b_k(n)\le b_k(n-\ell)\le b_k\big((n-\ell)-1\big)=b_k(\big(n-(\ell+1)\big)$$

by $(1.2.2)$, so by induction $b_k(n)\le b_k(1)$.

It is clear that $1$ has only one representation: the righthand side of $(1.2.1)$ is greater than $1$ if $s>0$, or if $s=0$ and $a_0>1$.